# Increase the height of an <ul> from a TAB

Tags: html, css, tabs, navigation, height

I'm currently working in creating a nice page which will contain 4 tabs. For tabs navigation I used `https://codepen.io/axelaredz/pen/ipome` , which looks great.
The issue here is that I need to have a different height for each section that sits under each tab. Some tabs will contain more content, some less.
From what I see, in the css I only have one height of 370px for the whole UL.
How can I make this code adjust the height automatically, or at least to add different heights for each tab content?
I tried adding a position relative and height: auto to the UL but it won't work.

Any ideas how I can make it work?

THanks,
//C

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
  <title>Pure CSS3 Tabs</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/3.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

  <div class="page">
    <h1>Pure CSS Tabs</h1>          

    <!-- tabs -->
    <div class="pcss3t pcss3t-effect-scale pcss3t-theme-1">
      <input type="radio" name="pcss3t" checked  id="tab1"class="tab-content-first">
      <label for="tab1"><i class="icon-bolt"></i>Tesla</label>
      <input type="radio" name="pcss3t" id="tab2" class="tab-content-2">
      <label for="tab2"><i class="icon-picture"></i>da Vinci</label>
      <input type="radio" name="pcss3t" id="tab3" class="tab-content-3">
      <label for="tab3"><i class="icon-cogs"></i>Einstein</label>
      <input type="radio" name="pcss3t" id="tab5" class="tab-content-last">
      <label for="tab5"><i class="icon-globe"></i>Newton</label>
      
      <ul>
        <li class="tab-content tab-content-first typography">
          <h1>Nikola Tesla</h1>
          <p>Serbian-American inventor, electrical engineer, mechanical engineer, physicist, and futurist best known for his contributions to the design of the modern alternating current (AC) electrical supply system.</p>
          <p>Tesla started working in the telephony and electrical fields before emigrating to the United States in 1884 to work for Thomas Edison. He soon struck out on his own with financial backers, setting up laboratories/companies to develop a range of electrical devices. His patented AC induction motor and transformer were licensed by George Westinghouse, who also hired Tesla as a consultant to help develop an alternating current system. Tesla is also known for his high-voltage, high-frequency power experiments in New York and Colorado Springs which included patented devices and theoretical work used in the invention of radio communication, for his X-ray experiments, and for his ill-fated attempt at intercontinental wireless transmission in his unfinished Wardenclyffe Tower project.</p><p>Tesla started working in the telephony and electrical fields before emigrating to the United States in 1884 to work for Thomas Edison. He soon struck out on his own with financial backers, setting up laboratories/companies to develop a range of electrical devices. His patented AC induction motor and transformer were licensed by George Westinghouse, who also hired Tesla as a consultant to help develop an alternating current system. Tesla is also known for his high-voltage, high-frequency power experiments in New York and Colorado Springs which included patented devices and theoretical work used in the invention of radio communication, for his X-ray experiments, and for his ill-fated attempt at intercontinental wireless transmission in his unfinished Wardenclyffe Tower project.</p>
          <p class="text-right"><em>Find out more about Nikola Tesla from <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikola_Tesla" target="_blank">Wikipedia</a>.</em></p>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>
    <!--/ tabs -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the codepen you provided, add an id to one of your li tags like this:

```
<li id="leo" class="tab-content tab-content-2 typography">
                    <h1>Leonardo da Vinci</h1>
                    <p>Italian Renaissance polymath: painter, sculptor, architect, musician, mathematician, engineer, inventor, anatomist, geologist, cartographer, botanist, and writer. His genius, perhaps more than that of any other figure, epitomized the Renaissance humanist ideal. Leonardo has often been described as the archetype of the Renaissance Man, a man of "unquenchable curiosity" and "feverishly inventive imagination". He is widely considered to be one of the greatest painters of all time and perhaps the most diversely talented person ever to have lived. According to art historian Helen Gardner, the scope and depth of his interests were without precedent and "his mind and personality seem to us superhuman, the man himself mysterious and remote". Marco Rosci states that while there is much speculation about Leonardo, his vision of the world is essentially logical rather than mysterious, and that the empirical methods he employed were unusual for his time.</p>
                    <p class="text-right"><em>Find out more about Leonardo da Vinci from <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonardo_da_Vinci" target="_blank">Wikipedia</a>.</em></p>
                </li>
```

Then in your CSS, reference the id you created like below and work the height from there.

```
    /**/
    /* height */
    /**/
    .pcss3t > ul,
    .pcss3t > ul > li {
        height: 390px;
    }
//leo is the id that has been added to the second tabs li tag
    #leo {
      height: 100px;
    }
```

EDIT: To note, I'm not sure why you would want to edit the height on the ul tag since each tab is separated based on the li and not ul. Either way if you wanted to work the ul you could do it in a similar fashion by adding an id.

Comment: That won't work because I'm limited to max 390px as the UL has. If I add for example 7000px height to that id, nothing will happen. And if I add 100px I will end up having a vertical scroll. I'm trying to expand the <ul> for each tab. Each one with a different height though.